# Dashboard activities next url throws an error

Tags: api, soundcloud

When trying to get next activities it shows this error:
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 125: EntityRef: expecting ';'
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

the url that i'm trying to get is taken from response.next_href.

This is happening on incoming tracks too.

thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question and include more information about the response you're getting? For example, is the EntityRef error what you get in the response body? What about response headers? 

Looks like an XML parsing error is happening somewhere. What if you edit the activities URL and append a '.json' or send an Accept header requesting a JSON representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue on next_href.
the problem is even i request a JSON data
next href returns XML data.
just added `&format=json` and problem is solved.
but everyone expect next_href to behave like the previous request, and not to modify the link.

you still need to check this response on your api too, for other developers.

thanks.